# Externally added frameworks are not copied when project is copied in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks

I have added external frameworks from my mac's Documents folder into my project.
Now when I copy this project to someother place and compile them I m getting errors .Its becoz those frameworks are not copied.Those frameworks appear to be in red colur in Frameworks group.
How can I make all the custom added frameworks to be copied when the project is copied to a newer place?

Comment: You could click on your framework, and select "Absolute Path" at "Location" in the Preferences on the right. Then you can copy your project wherever you want, and your frameworks will always be referenced to your "Documents" folder

Comment: But I dont find any "Absolute Path" when I right click on the frameworks.Where it will be ?

Comment: Don't right click on the Framework. Select your framework, and in Xcode - on the right, open the Utilities inspector (command+option+1) -> There is a popup named "Location" - there you should select "Absolute Path"

Comment: it same to like add files in project, simply paste files in project folder and add files via xcode

Comment: @BorisProhaska I have done it.Now they dont appear to be in red colour.But Im getting error "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h file not found"..Do I need to do anything elz?

Answer (score 0):

Add these framework first of all under build phases in link binary with libraries means drag & drop these framework there first & then try to add in another place.try it.

Comment: I have added in the same way..But still could n't copy

Comment: Download Facebook framework from here: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ ans install it on mac your issue is resolve with installation of framework...